# VBA Excel: Using IF statement to run a sub routines (from two selections) based on a cell value (ex. "1")

Tags: excel, vba

Need an example on how to code a VBA sub routine using IF statement based on a  cell value. For example, if value of cell = "1", run Code1 else run Code2

Currently, my workaround is on having two separate buttons to run the two codes.
My colleague informed me though that this may be a bad idea moving forward because requests  might increase the number  of buttons I  have to do.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: look at using a `select case` statement - it allows for more expansion in a neater way than multiple `if..else` type statements.

Comment: first, if you are looking for a cell value to call a routine, you don't need any code, you can use the `Worksheet_SelectionChange` event , and run the `If` or `Select Case` , from there

Answer (score 1):

You asked for an example:

```
Select Case ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Range("A1")
    Case 1 : myFunction1
    Case 2 : myFunction2
    Case 3 : myFunction3
    Case Else : MsgBox "Sorry, the option provided is not valid"
End Select
```

Where the value of A1 in the code above is 1, `myFunction1` will execute, where it's 2, `myFunction2` will run and so on.

The `Case Else` is used as a final catchall circumstance to handle a scenario you haven't specified directly.